# Zip and unzip files

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, zip

I am a programmer using VS2012. I am wanting to unzip a zip file (made with Winzip, filzip or other zip compression routines) and then also be able to zip the files back up into a zip file.

What is the best library to use for this and can I please have some sample code on how to use the library?

**EDIT**

I am using VB.net, here is my code:

```
Public Function extractZipArchive() As Boolean
    Dim zipPath As String = "c:\example\start.zip"
    Dim extractPath As String = "c:\example\extract"

    Using archive As ZipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath)
        For Each entry As ZipArchiveEntry In archive.Entries
            If entry.FullName.EndsWith(".txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
                entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName))
            End If
        Next
    End Using
End Function
```

What import statements do I need to use?
Currently I have added the following:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression
```

I am getting the error:

> Type 'ZipArchive' is not defined

How can I fix this error?

Comment: It's built in to the framework: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/381661/Creating-Zip-Files-Easily-in-NET-4-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio 2012 and the .NET Framework 4.5 [you can use the new compression library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/381661/Creating-Zip-Files-Easily-in-NET-4-5):

```cs
    //This stores the path where the file should be unzipped to,
    //including any subfolders that the file was originally in.
    string fileUnzipFullPath;
     
    //This is the full name of the destination file including
    //the path
    string fileUnzipFullName;
     
    //Opens the zip file up to be read
    using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipName))
    {
        //Loops through each file in the zip file
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry file in archive.Entries)
        {
            //Outputs relevant file information to the console
            Console.WriteLine("File Name: {0}", file.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("File Size: {0} bytes", file.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Compression Ratio: {0}", ((double)file.CompressedLength / file.Length).ToString("0.0%"));
     
            //Identifies the destination file name and path
            fileUnzipFullName = Path.Combine(dirToUnzipTo, file.FullName);
     
            //Extracts the files to the output folder in a safer manner
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileUnzipFullName))
            {
                //Calculates what the new full path for the unzipped file should be
                fileUnzipFullPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileUnzipFullName);
                            
                //Creates the directory (if it doesn't exist) for the new path
                Directory.CreateDirectory(fileUnzipFullPath);
     
                //Extracts the file to (potentially new) path
                file.ExtractToFile(fileUnzipFullName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I am actually using VB.net (sorry I should have stated that). Can you please have a look at my edited post?

Comment: Also, can I please have some help with code to create a zip file and then add files to it?

Comment: You can run his code through a code converter and it will do most of the work for you (they're always 100% accurate but they will get you most of the way there).  I use this one when convertering snippets for blog posts:  http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx

You can use **ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory** and **CreateFromDirectory**

This is the example:

> Imports System.IO
>
> Imports System.IO.Compression
>
> Module Module1
>
> Sub Main()
>
> ```
>    Dim startPath As String = "c:\example\start"
>    Dim zipPath As String = "c:\example\result.zip"
>    Dim extractPath As String = "c:\example\extract"
>
>    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath)
>    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath)
> ```
>
> End Sub
>
> End Module

Make sure you have referenced **System.IO.Compression.FileSystem** for using this function.

Comment: This is answer that worked for me in 2023. The original answer used Microsoft object and method names that have changed since this question was first posted. For Framework 4.7.2 that I am currently using, the .ExtractToDirectory method is available and working. The last point that Samuel Surya makes is very important: make sure you have the dll for Compression.FileSystem enabled in your project references.

Comment: The best answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Unanswered, although a while ago, so I'll still put my $0.02 in there for anyone else who hits this on keywords...

VB 2012 (.Net 4.5) added new features to System.IO.Compression (*System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll*) that will do what you want. We only had GZip before. You can still use the free [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) or [SharpZipLib](http://sharpziplib.com), of course.

The *ZipFile* class has 2 static methods that make simple compression/decompression drop-dead simple: *CreateFromDirectory* and *ExtractToDirectory*. Yo also have compression choices of *NoCompression*, *Fastest*, and *Optimal*.

One thing about it that struck me about your post was the concept of files (even archives) within archives. With the *ZipArchive* and *ZipArchiveEntry* classes you can now

ZipArchive:

```
Using zippedFile as ZipArchive = ZipFile.Open("foo.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Read)
    For Each ntry as ZipArchiveEntry In zippedFile.Entries
        Debug.Writeline("entry " & ntry.FullName & " is only " & ntry.CompressedLength.ToString)
    Next
End Using
```

Your question also was about adding to an existing archive. You can now do that like this:

```
Using zippedFile as ZipArchive = ZipFile.Open("foo.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Update)
    zippedFile.createEntry("bar.txt", CompressionLevel.Fastest)
    ' likewise you can get an entry already in there...
    Dim ntry As ZipArchiveEntry = zippedFile.GetEntry("wtf.doc")
    ' even delete an entry without need to decompress & compress again!
    ntry.Delete() ' !
End Using
```

Again, this was a while ago, but a lot of us still use 2012, and as this change won't be going anywhere in future versions, it should still prove helpful moving forward if anyone hits in on a keyword/tag search...

...and we didn't even *talk* about UTF-8 support!

Answer (score 2):

You probably aren't referencing `System.IO.Compression`. Check the box for that assembly reference and it should eliminate the error.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Dim fileStream As Stream = File.OpenRead("your file path")

    Using zipToOpen As FileStream = New FileStream(".......\My.zip", FileMode.CreateNew)
        Using archive As ZipArchive = New ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Create)
            Dim readmeEntry As ZipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry("your file path")
            fileStream.CopyTo(readmeEntry.Open())
        End Using
    End Using
```